# How to add a scope permanently in WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEA (JetBrains)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In WebStorm, when I work on Angular projects, I always need to hide all the `.spec.ts` files. To do that, I define a scope with the pattern

```
!file:src//**.spec.ts
```

It works well, but, I have to define this same scope for all the new projects, because every time I have a new project, this scope just disappears.

Is it possible to define this scope permanently, so that I don't need to define/add it for every new project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify scope settings for new projects in **File | Settings for New Projects... | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes** (**File | Default Settings  | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes** in previous versions):

[image]

These settings will be applied to newly created projects.

See also [IDEABKL-6853](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6853)

Comment: But it is not permanent, using this method, I still have to define the scope for every newly created project.

Comment: @BohaoLI Wrong. This will be defined for **every new project** created later (just as menu entry says: "Settings for New Projects"). There is no option to have IDE-wide scopes.

Comment: @LazyOne My bad, I didn't choose "Settings for New Projects". And now it is working.